# Can bootstrap be modularized in react?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

eg I have component A need only container class, and component B doesn't need anything, can we have something like

```js
import {container} from "component-bootstrap"

export default function CName() {
  return <div class={container}></div>
}
```

or maybe we could have

```js
import {Container} from "component-bootstrap"

export default function CName() {
  return <Container></Container>
}
```

I know there is react-bootstrap, but its style is still globalized.

Comment: Have you read the following web page?
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

Is it useful to you?

Comment: I created a trial repo, it won't able to apply css: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-trial-hrq9r4?file=/src/App.js CSS has to be imported, and it will be global.